# How to set web server to display URL not IP address?

Tags: linux, apache, web, server

I currently have an apache web server setup on my raspberry pi running Raspbian. I've opened the ports on my router and registered a domain name through a website. In the website I set the domain to forward to my pi's external IP address which works fine.

The problem I'm having is that when the browser gets to the site which is accessed by url, it displays the test page I have set up but in the address bar the IP is displayed and not the URL. Is there a way to change it so it will display my URL?

Comment: Have you set `ServerName` in apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an A record. Read the post below.
https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/a-record/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an `A` record to point the domain name at that IP address, instead of forwarding to a URL with the IP.